# How to use tags to use a specific gitlab-runner?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

How to use tags to use a specific gitlab-runner?
I wrote tag in .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
appBuild:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - android
```

I wrote "android" tag in runner config.
But job is in pending state and is waiting to be picked by a runner.
What is wrong?

Comment: Do you have a runner defined with the tag android declared at its registration ?

Comment: @Tensibai Yes, i declared it with tag Android in registration

Comment: Check your tags, check the settings => CI/CD of your project to be sure the runner is visible and check your runner logs, maybe it can't start properly due to something on your runner machine and is thus considered dead on gitlab point of view.

Comment: As long as you have a runner with the "android" tag, and your project has access to it, there is no reason your runner shouldn't pick up the job.

Comment: runner is visible in gitlab